# Loading SharedPreferences in another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner

Here's the problem. In my second class, I'm trying to load the SharedPreferences. Below I'll also include my first class.

```
//set label for journal questions
public TextView journalQuestionLabel;
public int counter = 0;
SharedPreferences preferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal);

    //TODO: Send saved preferences here
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("grammarOption", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selection = preferences.getInt("grammarOption", -1);
    Log.d("in onCreate", "preferences = " + selection);

}
```

When I test it, my debug log always prints -1. It won't load my shared preferences. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried the other answers on here and every tutorial, but they aren't working. Here is my code to set up and save my spinner preferences. I've checked this and it's working.

```
    private void setupSpinner() {
    // Create adapter for spinner. The list options are from the String array it will use
    // the spinner will use the default layout
    final ArrayAdapter grammarSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_grammar_options,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
    grammarSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    //Apply the adapter to the spinner
    grammarChoiceSpinner.setAdapter(grammarSpinnerAdapter);

    //Create shared preferences to store the spinner selection
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
            ("Selection", MODE_PRIVATE);

    editor = preferences.edit();

    // Create the intent to save the position
    grammarChoiceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //receive the string of the option and store it
            int grammarOptionPosition = grammarChoiceSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            //put the string in the editor
            editor.putInt("grammarOption", grammarOptionPosition);
            editor.commit();
            //make a toast so the user knows if it's not "select"
            if (grammarOptionPosition != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choice saved.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mGrammar = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Here it's called in onCreate()

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);

    //find the spinner to read user input
    grammarChoiceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    setupSpinner();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing wrong String in `getSharedPreferences(String, int)`.

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences("Selection", MODE_PRIVATE);
int selection = preferences.getInt("grammarOption", -1);
Log.d("in onCreate", "preferences = " + selection);
```

Give this a try.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! Such a simple solution - that fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `SharedPreference` key is same in both the class or even throughout the whole App.
While saving do like -

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putInt("grammerOption", 1).apply();
```

While Getting data from prefs do like -

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
int option = preference.getInt("grammerOption", -1);
```

PS,
Key for preference(which is `MY_PREFS` here) must be the same.